# Is there a way to quickly plot elisp functions with gnuplot?

Tags: elisp, gnuplot

Is there an emacs-lisp command which I could use to plot a collection of numbers with gnuplot, much like I can create simple line charts in Excel from an array of numbers?

For example, I would like to have a function called something like `plot-with-gnuplot` which I could call with something like:

```
(plot-with-gnuplot '((0 0.1) (0.1 1) (0.5 10)))
```

and have this produce a simple line plot going through those points.

Ultimately I will be using this to view mathematical functions that I am writing, it would be useful to be able to have a quick look at how my code is coming along by drawing a simple line plot of its values over a certain range.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://astro.berkeley.edu/~mkmcc/software/gnuplot-mode.html ... just some google foo

Comment: Thanks, had seen the gnuplot mode. I think the final answer is going to be to write some function that generates the data points and wraps them up in a gnuplot script file. In which case it will be helpful to use gnuplot functionality in the first instance -- leaving the lisp function just to generate the file and load it into another buffer (*first thoughts*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not exactly what you want but you may find [Org-babel-gnuplot](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-gnuplot.html) from org-mode useful. I've made an example file, it should work if you have [gnuplot.el](http://astro.berkeley.edu/~mkmcc/software/gnuplot-mode.html) and emacs24. Run the first code block (<kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>), and then run the third code block.

**test.org:**

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results silent
;; load gnuplot mode
(require 'gnuplot "~/Dropbox/emacs/gnuplot.el")
(require 'ob-gnuplot)
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: edata
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
'((0 0.1) (0.1 1) (0.5 10)))
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC gnuplot :file file.png :var data=edata
plot data w lp
#+END_SRC
```

[image: snapshot]